# How to implement the mapping from type to method call

Tags: c++, function, dictionary

I want to complete a mapping form type to method execution.

This sample code like this(The actual code is more complex):

```
int DoTask1(int num)
{
    cout << "DoTask1" << endl;
}

int DOTask2(int num)
{
    cout << "DoTask2" << endl;
}

static unordered_map<int, function<int(int)>> httpSrvFunc = {
        {1, DoTask1},
        {2, DOTask2}
};
int main() {
    httpSrvFunc[1](1);
    httpSrvFunc[2](1);
    return 0;
}
```

The core idea is to use different key value to execute different method(these method have the same type)

There are two question here:

1. Because the construct of map/unordered_map is not nonexcept and we can't catch the exception of static global variable initialization. This makes code execution dangerous.
2. I don't want to use if/else to judge perform different method, it look not smart. I also don't want to use simple array to store function, because the key may be Enum or some other type which is inconvenient as a subscript.

I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: You can as well initialize in `main()`. This would make httpSrvFunc a pointer, but good enough? Though I don't think creating an empty unordered_map would be problematic in any remotely normal circumstances. You can still fill it in `main()` if what you fill it with is too fancy.

Comment: As mentioned, you can initialize this map anywhere, not necessarily before main. Style-wise I don't see any problem with this approach, it is quite common pattern to store callbacks like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `switch` statement?

It is elegant, as it usually compiles to an elegant jump table.

Comment: I think it's similar to if/else. It increases the complexity of the function.